# Number of query values and destination fields are not the same. Error Message

Tags: visual-studio

I'm having an error message with my codes in visual basic. Please help. Thanks.

The error says:

[image: Number of query values and destination fields are not the same.]

Private Sub btnAdd_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand

```
If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
    cnn.Open()
End If

cmd.Connection = cnn

If Me.txtID.Tag & "" = "" Then
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ProfessorListTable(ID,LastName,FirstName,MI,Gender,Department,ContactNo,Address,EmailAddress,YearEmployed)" & _
        " VALUES(" & Me.txtID.Text & ",'" & Me.txtLName.Text & "','" & _
        Me.txtFName.Text & "','" & Me.txtMI.Text & "','" & _
        Me.txtGender.Text & "','" & Me.txtDept.Text & "','" & _
        Me.txtNo.Text & "','" & Me.txtAddress.Text & "','" & _
        Me.txtEAdd.Text & "','" & Me.txtYear.Text & "',')"

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Else
    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE ProfessorListTable " & _
    " SET txtID=" & Me.txtID.Text & _
    ", LastName='" & Me.txtLName.Text & "'" & _
    ", FirstName='" & Me.txtFName.Text & "'" & _
    ", MI='" & Me.txtMI.Text & "'" & _
    ", Gender='" & Me.txtGender.Text & "'" & _
    ", Department='" & Me.txtDept.Text & "'" & _
    ", ContactNo='" & Me.txtNo.Text & _
    ", Address='" & Me.txtAddress.Text & "'" & _
    ", EmailAddress='" & Me.txtEAdd.Text & "'" & _
    ", YearEmployed='" & Me.txtYear.Text & _
    " WHERE stdid=" & Me.txtID.Tag
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()


End If


RefreshData()
```

End Sub

The

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had extra Comma (,) here

```
& Me.txtYear.Text & "','
```

So it's leads to 11 value instead of 10

And Address is reserved word so use it as [Address]

**Try like this**

```
Private Sub btnAdd_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand

If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
    cnn.Open()
End If

cmd.Connection = cnn

If Me.txtID.Tag & "" = "" Then
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ProfessorListTable(ID,LastName,FirstName,MI,Gender,Department,ContactNo,[Address],EmailAddress,YearEmployed)" & _
        " VALUES(" & Me.txtID.Text & ",'" & Me.txtLName.Text & "','" & _
        Me.txtFName.Text & "','" & Me.txtMI.Text & "','" & _
        Me.txtGender.Text & "','" & Me.txtDept.Text & "','" & _
        Me.txtNo.Text & "','" & Me.txtAddress.Text & "','" & _
        Me.txtEAdd.Text & "','" & Me.txtYear.Text & "')"

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Else
    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE ProfessorListTable " & _
    " SET txtID=" & Me.txtID.Text & _
    ", LastName='" & Me.txtLName.Text & "'" & _
    ", FirstName='" & Me.txtFName.Text & "'" & _
    ", MI='" & Me.txtMI.Text & "'" & _
    ", Gender='" & Me.txtGender.Text & "'" & _
    ", Department='" & Me.txtDept.Text & "'" & _
    ", ContactNo='" & Me.txtNo.Text & _
    ", [Address]='" & Me.txtAddress.Text & "'" & _
    ", EmailAddress='" & Me.txtEAdd.Text & "'" & _
    ", YearEmployed='" & Me.txtYear.Text & _
    " WHERE stdid=" & Me.txtID.Tag
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()


End If
RefreshData()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. I committed another mistake. it says :

The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect.

Comment: Address is reserved keyword so use like [Address]

Comment: I tried to use the [Address] but it shows the same error. For more detailed error message. Kindly look at this one, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21770789/the-select-statement-includes-a-reserved-word-or-an-argument-name-that-is-misspe


Thank you so much