# The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect. Error Message

Tags: visual-studio-2008

So much thanks to those who answer my question. I'm in a hurry so i need to work it out now.

Here's another error

[image: The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect]

The code is as follows:

```
Private Sub RefreshData()
    If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        cnn.Open()
    End If

    Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT txtID as [ID], " & _
                                         "txtLName as [LastName], txtFName as [FirstName], txtMI as [MI] " & _
                                         "txtGender as [Gender], txtDept as [Department], txtNo as [ContactNo]" & _
                                         "txtAddress as [Address], txtEAdd as [EmailAddress], txtYear as [YearEmployed]", cnn)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    da.Fill(dt)
    Me.dgvProfessorList.DataSource = dt

    cnn.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: Look at the query you're asking it to run `txtMI as [MI] txtGender as [Gender]`. You probably want a `FROM` in there too.

Comment: Oh i forgot to add the FROM statement. But when I tried to put it, it encounters the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Your Query might be wrong and you have missed **Comma (,)** to separate the Columns. It should be

```
 Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT [ID],[LastName],[FirstName],[MI],[Gender],[Department],[ContactNo],[Address],[EmailAddress],[YearEmployed] From ProfessorListTable", cnn)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it doesn't eliminate the error. The same error exists.

Comment: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '[MI] [Gender]'.

this is now the error. I'm so sorry for my consecutive questions. I'm really a beginner with this matter

Comment: Check my answer.. you have missed comma (,) between [Mi][Gender]

Comment: http://aroundtheworld2k13.wordpress.com/category/logical-thinking/ go through this link and particularly chek this part (Feel you are talented than computer (Which is the truth)) n it..!!